# Android keyboard doesn't close

Tags: android, ime

I've been developing a custom keyboard for Android, and I'm experiencing some weird behaviour when changing keyboards...
On the first run (either after being build from Android Studio or distributed via Fabric), the keyboard will not close, when I use:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(getToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
```

It will open the next input method behind my keyboard... But my keyboard will be forced upon on top of the other keyboard... It will even stay there, if you go to the home screen... But as soon as the device has been restarted, the keyboard changes without any issues... I've been reading up on this, and I've seen there was some issues with keyboards in previous versions of Android, are there still any?

Below you can see the relevant code:

```
public class CustomKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    public final static int CodeRowFourGlobe = 55041;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.custom_keyboard);
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    private IBinder getToken() {
        final Dialog dialog = getWindow();
        if (dialog == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return window.getAttributes().token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeRowFourGlobe) {
            InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(getToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
        } else {
            /* not relevant */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }
}
```

Do you have any idea if it's a problem with how I'm changing the keyboard or a known Android issue?

Comment: You are recreating an instance of `InputMethodManager` every time in your onKey() method.  It is better to create a class-level instance inside of your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this it works for me anytime

```
public static void hideKeyboard( Context context ) {

try {
InputMethodManager inputManager = ( InputMethodManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );

View view = ( (Activity) context ).getCurrentFocus();
if ( view != null ) {
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );
}
} catch ( Exception e ) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

Comment: How would you use it? I can't call it with 'this' as my class can't be cast to an acitivity

Comment: this is method..and call this method hideKeyboard(youractivity.this) or use getApplicatioContext..whereever you trying to hide keyboard

Comment: dont use in this class..use in activity or fragment..directly

Comment: I don't have any fragments... The app only has the main activity and the service class that implements the keyboard, so I'm limited in where I can call it other than from my service class

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of the ime is handled by the system itself.

I faced a similar issue a few days ago and fixed it by coding the IME from scratch again & doing all the time consuming stuff on background thread (like getTextBeforeCursor()/getTextAfterCursor, local database read/write, etc.).

If you switch from/to another IME more than once and the same thing happens, then it's the issue i'm talking about.

So maybe you are invoking something that takes time or gets the IME stuck. Just refer the documentation of the calls you are making to check if they take indeterminate time.

Hope this helps.